# Best way to filter out none's from Array of options

Tags: typescript, option-type, fp-ts

Let's say I have the following types:

```
type OptionalArray = ReadonlyArray<Option<number>>
type DatabaseWriteArray = ReadonlyArray<number>
```

So how do I convert between the types? The following works but feels super messy:

```
const filterOptionals = (optionalArray: OptionalArray): DatabaseWriteArray => {
  const filteredNullableArray = optionalArray.filter(isSome).map(toNullable)
  return filteredNullableArray.filter(num => num !== null)
}
```

At this point I'm not even sure why I'm bothering with Options at all if I immediately have to drop out of them into nullables. I could achieve the same result, with one less step using `number | null`. So what would be "the `fp-ts` way" to do this?

Answer (score 3):

Without getting too much into details I can suggest using `readonlyArray.compact` which does exactly this (even has the same signature):

```
import { readonlyArray } from 'fp-ts';

const filterOptionals = readonlyArray.compact;
```

Answer (score 1):

This example has less complexity:

```js
const filterOptionals = (optionalArray: OptionalArray): DatabaseWriteArray => 
    optionalArray.reduce((acc,elem)=>isSome(elem)?[...acc,elem.value]:acc,[])
```

Answer (score 0):

I've found the following way to do this:

```
const filterOptionals = (optionalArray: OptionalArray): DatabaseWriteArray => {
  const filteredNullableArray = optionalArray.filter(isSome).map(item => item.value)
}
```

This feels cleaner (though I'm obviously open to other suggestions)